# Basic python encryption stuck

Tags: python, text, python-2.x

I'm stuck on this problem:

> Write a program to encrypt a file. You should read file name from the terminal, then read the contents of that file.
>
> Encryption is then done as follows: `a` is transformed to `z`, `b` to `y` and so on. Similarly for uppercase characters. Non-alphabet characters are left as they are.

This is what I've done so far:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter name of file you want to encrypt: ")
fhand = open(fname + ".txt", "r")
a = fhand.read()

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i].isalpha():
        a[i] = chr(ord(a[i]) - 26)
```

Comment: Please choose a better title for your question.

Comment: 'c' is 'x' , d is w e is v

Comment: There are several problems (trying to mutate a string is one of them, another is that your algorithm is invalid: You won't get a->z, b->y etc. by simply subtracting 26). What *exactly*  are you struggling with?

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer, but just hints to help you to write the final code by yourself.

- *read content of the file* - unless you have a good reason not to do (lesson is still to come, old Python version, ...) you should use the `with` construct which gurantees proper closing of file, whatever may happen :

  ```
  with open(fname+".txt","r") as fhand:
      a = fhand.read()
      ...
  ```
- *'a' is transformed to 'z' 'b' to 'y' and so on* : you should control that the char is between `'a'` and `'z'` and transform only if it is :

  ```
  if c >= 'a' and c <='z':
      c = 'z' + 'a' - c   # 'z' - new_c =  c-'a' : a=>z, ...
  ```
- *Similarly for uppercase charecters. non-alphabet is left as it is* : ok do the same for characters between `'A'` and `'Z'`
- a Python string is a non mutable sequence ! Do not use `a[i] = ...` but instead build a new string and add characters to it (*) :

  ```
  result = ''
  ...
          result = result + ...
  ```

Mixing that all it should not be hard to build your script.

(*) alternatively, you could transform initial string in a list of characters, replace characters in the list and then `join` the list to build back a string. Left as a new exercise :-)

Comment: `'a' <= c <= 'z'` would be nicer.

Answer (score 1):

@Serge Ballesta wrote a good way of handling files.

As for the transformation, Python has its own cool way of doing that. Here's an example:

```py
from string import maketrans, ascii_lowercase
cypher = maketrans(ascii_lowercase, ascii_lowercase[::-1])
print 'abcde'.translate(cypher)
```

which would output `zyxwv`.

`string.maketrans` takes same length string arguments in order to produce a cypher for the transformation you'd later do. In the above example, I'm taking all lowercase ascii characters for 1st argument, and the reverse of it as 2nd.

In Python3 you'd go with `bytes.maketrans`.